"I think she will be (OR) going to be late”
What's the correct tense?


Salma is always late. I think she will be (or) going to be late tomorrow, too.




Yasmine is going to visit (or) is visiting Paris next year. She has got an invitation.


The teacher told me that if there is an evidence, choose "going to" and I don't know being always late is considered an evidence or not. The second one I don't know having an invitation is considered an arrangement, so I should choose present continuous or it is not.

What is your doubt in these sentences?  What resources have you looked at?  The simple answer is that "any of these tenses is fine".  But why are you unsure?

Because it's a choice question in my textbook on forms of the future so I got confused.I don't know what to choose.

Yes, I thought this was a textbook question. You should read your textbook. Most textbooks explain grammar.  If you don't understand your textbook, you should ask your teacher first. They are paid to answer this kind of question.  If you have read your textbook and asked your teacher, and you are still unsure, then please tell us about this. There's no point in asking questions from the textbook.  That's not your question, that's just a request for us to do your homework.

But, as I said,  both "will be late" and "is going to be late" are correct grammar (and idiomatic, and mean the same) "Is going to visit" and "Is visiting... next year" differ only in nuance,  both are acceptable and correct grammar (and idiomatic)

Please edit the question to make it clear what you are asking, and also remove the duplication.

The teacher told me that if there is an evidence, choose" going to "and I don't know being always late is considered an evidence or not. The second one I don't know having an invitation is considered an arrangement so I should choose present continuous or it is not. Thanks anyway.

We don't say "an evidence" in English. You should look at all the answers to this on this site.

Thanks. I got it.

Choose the correct answer:


Salma is always late. I think she will be or going to be late tomorrow, too.
Yasmine is going to visit or is visiting Paris next year. She has got an invitation.


The correct answers:

Salma is always late. I think she will be late tomorrow, too.


Explanation: "will be" is used for Prediction based on past behaviour.


Yasmine is going to visit  Paris next year. She has got an invitation.


Explanation: "Going to" is commonly used to indicate a planned future action, especially one that is influenced by a present situation or intention (the invitation Yasmine received).


Many thanks. I really appreciate your help.
